# C# MVC (Umbraco 8) - Receiving a recurrent warning in home

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I have an Umbraco 8 c# MVC website and have realized I'm having a lot of recurrent log warnings that are making my log file very big.

The log warning message is:

```
    The current Document Type home matches a locally declared controller of type "ACC_UMBRACO.Controllers.HomeController". 
Custom Controllers for Umbraco routing must implement '"Umbraco.Web.Mvc.IRenderController"' and inherit from '"System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase"'.
```

My resumed config > umbracoSettings.config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<settings>

  <!--
    umbracoSettings.config configuration documentation can be found here:
    https://our.umbraco.xxx/documentation/using-umbraco/config-files/umbracoSettings/
    Many of the optional settings are not explicitly listed here
    but can be found in the online documentation.
    -->

    <backOffice>
        <tours enable="false"></tours>
    </backOffice>

  <content>

    <errors>
      <error404>1</error404>
      <!--
        The value for error pages can be:
        * A content item's GUID ID      (example: 26C1D84F-C900-4D53-B167-E25CC489DAC8)
        * An XPath statement            (example: //errorPages[@nodeName='My cool error']
        * A content item's integer ID   (example: 1234)
      -->
      <!--
        <error404>
            <errorPage culture="default">26C1D84F-C900-4D53-B167-E25CC489DAC8</errorPage>
            <errorPage culture="en-US">D820E120-6865-4D88-BFFE-48801A6AC375</errorPage>
        </error404>
       -->
    </errors>

    <notifications>
      <!-- the email that should be used as from mail when umbraco sends a notification -->
      <!-- you can add a display name to the email like this: <email>Your display name here &lt;your@email.here&gt;</email> -->
      <email>accit@byrom.plc.uk</email>
    </notifications>


    <!-- How Umbraco should handle errors during macro execution. Can be one of the following values:
         - inline - show an inline error within the macro but allow the page to continue rendering. Historial Umbraco behaviour.
         - silent - Silently suppress the error and do not render the offending macro.
         - throw  - Throw an exception which can be caught by the global error handler defined in Application_OnError. If no such
                    error handler is defined then you'll see the Yellow Screen Of Death (YSOD) error page.
         Note the error can also be handled by the umbraco.macro.Error event, where you can log/alarm with your own code and change the behaviour per event. -->
    <MacroErrors>inline</MacroErrors>

    <!-- These file types will not be allowed to be uploaded via the upload control for media and content -->
    <disallowedUploadFiles>ashx,aspx,ascx,config,cshtml,vbhtml,asmx,air,axd,swf,xml,xhtml,html,htm,php,htaccess</disallowedUploadFiles>

    <!-- You can specify your own background image for the login screen here. This path is relative to the ~/umbraco path. The default location is: /umbraco/assets/img/login.jpg -->
    <loginBackgroundImage>assets/img/login.jpg</loginBackgroundImage>

  </content>

  <security>
    <!-- set to true to auto update login interval (and there by disabling the lock screen -->
    <keepUserLoggedIn>false</keepUserLoggedIn>
    <!-- by default this is true and if not specified in config will be true. set to false to always show a separate username field in the back office user editor -->
    <usernameIsEmail>true</usernameIsEmail>
    <!-- change in 4.8: Disabled users are now showed dimmed and last in the tree. If you prefer not to display them set this to true -->
    <hideDisabledUsersInBackoffice>false</hideDisabledUsersInBackoffice>
  </security>

  <requestHandler>
    <!-- this ensures that all url segments are turned to ASCII as much as we can -->
    <urlReplacing toAscii="try" />
  </requestHandler>

  
  <web.routing
    trySkipIisCustomErrors="true"
    internalRedirectPreservesTemplate="false" disableAlternativeTemplates="false" validateAlternativeTemplates="false" disableFindContentByIdPath="false"
    umbracoApplicationUrl="https://xxx.local.xxx/umbraco">
  </web.routing>

  
  <keepAlive disableKeepAliveTask="false" keepAlivePingUrl="{umbracoApplicationUrl}/api/keepalive/ping" />
</settings>
```

All my controllers inherits from Umbraco.Controllers.BaseController:

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IUmbracoContextFactory _context;
    private readonly DictionaryManager _dictionaryManager;

    public HomeController(IUmbracoContextFactory context, DictionaryManager dictionaryManager)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dictionaryManager = dictionaryManager;
    }
    .......
}

public class BaseController : SurfaceController
{
  .....
}
```

I really need to stop this warning, so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: you are supposed to implement IRenderController in you controller ,HomeController : BaseController, IRenderController

Comment: Thanks for your help @sayah imad, I've already resolved the problem and posted my own answer in case is useful for anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question in case it helps anyone else with this problem.
As far as I was investigating, Umbraco uses its own "Home" controller, and if you create a local "Home" controller (as in my case), it makes a little conflict. The app will continue working, but you'll receive plenty of warnings.

My solution was simply rename my "Home" controller to a different name.